# d.rast multiple times

Tags: python, raster, grass-gis, batch, display

I am using GRASS 7.2.0 on Windows 8.1 and I have 107 raster files, converted from r3.to.rast which I want to display all at once.

I put in Python console (2.7.5) every name of rasters into variable d (list) and type:

```
for item in d:
    grass.raster.run_command("d.rast", map = item)
```

and it crashed if writes:

> neither monitor (managed by d.mon command) nor grass_render_immediate
>   (used for direct rendering) defined

I tried to run d.mon but no help.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is yet a feature wish: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2233

For now, use the PNG driver instead of the wx0 display, i.e. you need to render the output into a file. For an overview, see

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/displaydrivers.html

especially the

- https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/pngdriver.html, or
- https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/cairodriver.html

The d.rast (or other display commands) will all render into the specified file which you can visualise afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add them all into GRASS GUI, there is a toolbar button 'Add multiple raster or vector map layers' in the Layer Manager toolbar (top row). In the dialog you can then filter the maps and add only the maps you need.

Comment: I realized I have more complex problem: I want to show all of my rasters to complete my 3D model and in GRASS GIS there you can display only 12 rasters at once.